# Print only if all the second index element has same value in a nested list python

Tags: python, list

I am new to python and I am trying to print only second element of a list has same value in the nested list if one the second index element is different print it in else statement

```py
jobs_name = ['nbu.stn.prd.allbackups.box.lp2', 'SU'], ['nbu.stn.prd.1800.box.lp2', 'RU'], ['nbu.stn.prd.1810.box.lp2', 'RU']

def check_box():
    for j in jobs_name:
        if j[1] == j[1] :
            res = " ".join(j)
            print("Status of the box: " + res)
        else:
            res = " ".join(j)
            print("Status of the boxes: " + res)

check_box()
```

Comment: I think you need to explain better what you're trying to achieve. Or provide an example of the output you expect for a specific array.

Comment: Below is the nested list. I want to print if all the second value is "RU" in a if satement and if one of the second value is other than "RU" it should go to else statement
jobs_name= ['nbu.stn.prd.allbackups.box.lp2', 'SU'], ['nbu.stn.prd.1800.box.lp2', 'RU'], ['nbu.stn.prd.1810.box.lp2', 'RU']

Comment: What is the expected output if all 'RU' in second element and if it not? Edit in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `all()` and `elif`:

```
jobs_name = [
    ['nbu.stn.prd.allbackups.box.lp2', 'SU'], 
    ['nbu.stn.prd.1800.box.lp2', 'RU'], 
    ['nbu.stn.prd.1810.box.lp2', 'RU']
]

def check_box():
    for j in jobs_name:
        if all(j[1] == 'RU' for j in jobs_name):
            print("Status of the box:", *j)
        elif j[1] != 'RU':
            print("Status of the boxes:", *j)


check_box()

# Status of the boxes: nbu.stn.prd.allbackups.box.lp2 SU
```

Comment: Its working .Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```py
jobs_name= ['nbu.stn.prd.allbackups.box.lp2', 'SU'], ['nbu.stn.prd.1800.box.lp2', 'RU'], ['nbu.stn.prd.1810.box.lp2', 'RU']

def check_box():
    for j in jobs_name:
        if  j[1] == 'RU':
            res = " ".join(j)
            print("Status of the box: "+res )
        else:
            res = " ".join(j)
            print("Status of the boxes:"+res)

check_box()
```

I'm not sure why you check `j[1] ==  j[1]`, if you want to print if the second element is 'RU' then do that with `j[1] == 'RU'`.

Code works fine:

output

```
Status of the boxes:nbu.stn.prd.allbackups.box.lp2 SU
Status of the box: nbu.stn.prd.1800.box.lp2 RU
Status of the box: nbu.stn.prd.1810.box.lp2 RU
```

Comment: Many thanks I tried it but it "if statement" output and not else  statement because if statement should only print if all second value are "RU" in the above one has got "SU".
Output I am getting:
Status of the box:  nbu.stn.prd.1800.box.lp2 RU
Status of the box:  nbu.stn.prd.1810.box.lp2 RU

Comment: Code works fine?

Comment: No its not working.

Comment: Then I don't understand what you need. If you could post example inputs and outputs that'd be great

Answer (score 0):

Code will always print the same message, because the condition `j[1] == j[1]` is always true, since it's comparing the second element of the same list.

my suggestion is, you should compare the second elements of different lists.

may be use `set()`

```
jobs_name = [['nbu.stn.prd.allbackups.box.lp2', 'SU'], ['nbu.stn.prd.1800.box.lp2', 'RU'], ['nbu.stn.prd.1810.box.lp2', 'RU']]

def check_box():
    unique_second_elements = set()
    status_list = []

    for j in jobs_name:
        if j[1] in unique_second_elements:
            status_list.append(f"Status of the box: {j[0]} {j[1]} (Same)")
        else:
            unique_second_elements.add(j[1])
            status_list.append(f"Status of the box: {j[0]} {j[1]}")

    return status_list

status_list = check_box()
print(status_list)

for status in status_list:
    print(status)
```

This will give output based on whether the second elements are the same or different.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes it does worked out and below is the output.But any way to print this output in a list that will meet my requirements

Status of the boxes: {'nbu.stn.prd.allbackups.box.lp2'} {'RU'}
Status of the box: {'nbu.stn.prd.1800.box.lp2'} {'RU'}
Status of the box: {'nbu.stn.prd.1810.box.lp2'} {'RU'}

Comment: added the values to list as a new list. Can you check if this works for you.

Comment: Please see the output below , though the second item is "RU" for all the list, the output is different. print of (same) in if statement is not working and its going to else for the first list .Refer the output below.

Status of the box: nbu.stn.prd.allbackups.box.lp2 RU
Status of the box: nbu.stn.prd.1800.box.lp2 RU (same)
Status of the box: nbu.stn.prd.1810.box.lp2 RU (same)